# Laravel 5.1 return eloquent between time_start and time_end

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Here's my Sample Table:

reservation_date | time_start | time_end
   7/10/2017     |  12:00:00  | 14:00:00

what i'm trying to do is to return all reservations between time_start and time_end base on the request by the user. and sub/add 2 hours from time_start and time_end to prevent conflicts. I tried

```
$times_data = $this->getTimesData($request->reservation_time_start, $request->reservation_time_end);

$reservations =  $reservations->whereBetween('reservation_time_start', $times_data)

protected function getTimesData($time_start, $time_end)
    {

        $time_from = $this->getTimeFrom($time_start);

        $time_to = $this->getTimeTo($time_end);

        return [$time_from, $time_to];
    }

protected function getTimeFrom($time)
    {
        $time = Carbon::parse($time);

        return $time->subHours(2)->toTimeString();
    }


    protected function getTimeTo($time)
    {
        $time = Carbon::parse($time);

        return $time->addHours(2)->toTimeString();
    }
```

But the result is not what i expected. i also tried

```
->whereRaw("(reservation_time_start BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (reservation_time_end BETWEEN ? AND ?) ",$times_data)
```

but it returns null. Please help.

Comment: The where raw part you've tried required 4 parameters but you supplied it with two. Try `array_merge($times_data,$times_data)`

Answer (score 0):

check the laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries
I think you want to do something like that:

```
->whereBetween('reservation_time_start', [$time_from, $time_to])
->whereBetween('reservation_time_end', [$time_from, $time_to])
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem:

i used whereRaw and i found out that when i used double quotes(inside whereRaw parameter), it returns null. then i change it to single quote then my problem solved. Heres my query,

```
$reservations->whereRaw('((reservation_time_start >= ? AND reservation_time_start <= ?) OR (reservation_time_end <= ? AND reservation_time_end >= ?))',[$time_start, $time_end, $time_end, $time_start])
->whereIn('reservation_status_id', [1, 2, 3])
->ofReservationDate($request->reservation_date);
```